# Comparing values conditionally

Tags: excel, if-statement, comparison, excel-formula, vba

The data below is in an Excel sheet. The data is sorted on Column A (`Cluster`) and a group of values in Column B (`Town`) is associated with a `Cluster`. In the example below, the first five towns in Column B belong to Cluster `A`. Similarly, the next four towns belong to the Cluster  `M`.

The requirement is that the first `Town` of each `Cluster` should be the same as the `Cluster` name itself. In the example below the first town of Cluster A is `A` so in Column C (`Check`), a `1` has been displayed. For Cluster M however, the first town is not `M` (it is `N`), hence Column C has `0` in it. Subsequently, in row 8, the cluster name matches with the town name. Hence a `1` is displayed in Column C.

How do I do this using either Excel Formulas or a macro?

```
+--------+---------+------+-------+
| Row No | Cluster | Town | Check |
+--------+---------+------+-------+
|      1 | A       | A    |     1 |
|      2 | A       | B    |       |
|      3 | A       | C    |       |
|      4 | A       | D    |       |
|      5 | A       | E    |       |
|      6 | M       | N    |     0 |
|      7 | M       | O    |       |
|      8 | M       | M    |     1 |
|      9 | M       | A    |       |
+--------+---------+------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your columns labelled, in C2 and copied down to suit please try:

```
=IF(A2=B2,1,IF(A1<>A2,0,""))
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. Will try it out on the actual data and post a comment here, in case I need more help.